# Sum multiple keys and merge to one object based off a specific key

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have an array of objects and want to group these by a specified key: 'name', and sum all of their values into one object:

```
[
  { 
    name: "test1",
    value1: 100,
    value2: 100,
    value3: 100
  },
  { 
    name: "test1",
    value1: 100,
    value2: 100,
    value3: 100
  },
  { 
    name: "test2",
    value1: 200,
    value2: 100,
    value3: 100
  },
  { 
    name: "test2",
    value1: 200,
    value2: 100,
    value3: 100
  }, 
  { 
    name: "test3",
    value1: 100,
    value2: 100,
    value3: 100
  }
]
```

And the result I want would have this structure:

```
[
  {
    name: "test1",
    value1: 200,
    value2: 200,
    value3: 200
  },
  { 
    name: "test2",
    value1: 400,
    value2: 200,
    value3: 200
  },
  {
    name: "test3",
    value1: 100,
    value2: 100,
    value3: 100
  }
]
```

How would I go about doing this? I can currently get the sum of one key by using this method:

```
  const total_sum_data = (arr, key, value) => {
    const map = new Map();
    for (const obj of arr) {
      const currSum = map.get(obj[key]) || 0;
      map.set(obj[key], currSum + obj[value]);
    }
    const res = Array.from(map, ([k, v]) => ({ [key]: k, [value]: v }));
    return res;
  };
```

But not sure how to merge the results into one object with the specified key.

Answer (score 1):

You can [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) the array to an accumulator object (`a`) by [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) each object into its `name` and `values`, and summing all the values for each name in the accumulator object. Then you just need to retrieve the accumulator's [object values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) to get to your final result:

```
const result = Object.values(data.reduce((a, {name, ...values}) => {
  a[name] ??= { name };
  Object.entries(values).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    a[name][key] ??= 0;
    a[name][key] += value;
  });
  return a;
} , {}));
```

This solution has a time complexity of *O(n)*. It will gracefully handle cases where new values are added (`value4`, `value5`, ...), and cases where not all values are present in all objects.

---

**Complete snippet:**

```js
const data = [{
  name: "test1",
  value1: 100,
  value2: 100,
  value3: 100
}, {
  name: "test1",
  value1: 100,
  value2: 100,
  value3: 100
}, {
  name: "test2",
  value1: 200,
  value2: 100,
  value3: 100
}, {
  name: "test2",
  value1: 200,
  value2: 100,
  value3: 100
}, {
  name: "test3",
  value1: 100,
  value2: 100,
  value3: 100
}];

const result = Object.values(data.reduce((a, {name, ...values}) => {
  a[name] ??= { name };
  Object.entries(values).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    a[name][key] ??= 0;
    a[name][key] += value;
  });
  return a;
} , {}));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I've never seen this syntax before: `??=` nor can I find documentation on it, what is this doing? (also looks like webpack is unable to compile unless using a specific loader)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_assignment

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
const total_sum_data = (arr, key) => {
  const map = new Map();
  for (const obj of arr) {
    const groupKey = obj[key];
    if (!map.has(groupKey)) {
      map.set(groupKey, { [key]: groupKey });
    }
    const currObj = map.get(groupKey);
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(k => {
      if (k !== key) {
        currObj[k] = (currObj[k] || 0) + obj[k];
      }
    });
  }
  return Array.from(map.values());
};

console.log(total_sum_data(arr,"name"));
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved using Map and reduce.

while using Map here is a code:

```
const map = new Map();

for (const item of data) {
  if (!map.has(item.name)) {
    map.set(item.name, {
      name: item.name,
      value1: item.value1,
      value2: item.value2,
      value3: item.value3
    });
  } else {
    map.get(item.name).value1 += item.value1;
    map.get(item.name).value2 += item.value2;
    map.get(item.name).value3 += item.value3;
  }
}
console.log(Array.from(map.values()));
```

and while using reduce it can be done like this

```
const groupedSum = data.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  const objIndex = acc.findIndex(obj => obj.name === curr.name);
  if (objIndex === -1) {
    acc.push({ name: curr.name, value1: curr.value1, value2: curr.value2, value3: curr.value3 });
  } else {
    acc[objIndex].value1 += curr.value1;
    acc[objIndex].value2 += curr.value2;
    acc[objIndex].value3 += curr.value3;
  }
  return acc;
}, []);
console.log(groupedSum);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope below logic will help you

```js
let array = [
  { 
    name: "test1",
    value1: 100,
    value2: 100,
    value3: 100
  },
  { 
    name: "test1",
    value1: 100,
    value2: 100,
    value3: 100
  },
  { 
    name: "test2",
    value1: 200,
    value2: 100,
    value3: 100
  },
  { 
    name: "test2",
    value1: 200,
    value2: 100,
    value3: 100
  }, 
  { 
    name: "test3",
    value1: 100,
    value2: 100,
    value3: 100
  },

]


let reduceArr = array.reduce((prev, next) =>{
    if (next.name in prev) {
      prev[next.name].value1 += next.value1;
      prev[next.name].value2 += next.value2;
      prev[next.name].value3 += next.value3;
    } else {
       prev[next.name] = next;
    }
    return prev;
  }, {});

let result = Object.values(reduceArr);


console.log(result)
```

Comment: `Object.keys(reduceArr).map(id => reduceArr[id]);` →　`Object.values(reduceArr);`